# package org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to compile this:

```java
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class BCrypt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int strength = 10;
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(strength, new SecureRandom());
        System.out.println(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(args[0]));
    }
}
```

like this:

```bash
$ javac -cp spring-security-crypto-5.5.1.jar BCrypt.java
```

and I'm getting this error:

> BCrypt.java:1: error: package org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt does not exist

I gather I need to install something but the documentation for Spring is hopelessly unhelpful.  can anyone suggest how to fix this?

here's my Java info:

> openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>
> Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>
> Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)

Comment: I rarely compile directly, but I do recall that (at least in older versions of Java) one would specify the path to the .jar like `javac -cp '.:/spring-security-crypto-5.5.1.jar' BCrypt.java`. I doubt its necessary, but could you give it a try?

Comment: I think the issue is I don't have the jarfile.  I'm having a devil of a time just finding it.  doesn't java have a central repository of modules as is available in every other environment? some way for me to just do `npm install ...`?

Comment: Yes, but modern Java usually does this through Maven or Gradle, not by downloading the libraries manually. It allows to ship the whole project with it's resources and not to hope the server/pod is properly set, which is a thing in Java. I actually found very confusing that you tried to use Spring Security, as it is a module of the Spring Framework. I honestly do not know if Spring lets you download its modules as jars, really.

Comment: In other words, you'll need either a Maven or Gradle project, more likely.

Comment: Or, you can try a different library that does let you download a jar, like [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html). Couldn't edit previous comment as I forgot the name of this library.

Comment: I found the library here: https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/5.5.1 but it seems like such a hokey way to do things.  I don't even know if I can trust it

Comment: and I'm trying to figure out what the actual url is for the library  so I can curl it but the website has gone to lengths to obfuscate the location.  it's such a suboptimal setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245610/discussion-between-ekkis-and-jetto-martinez).